# Adventureworks and MSSQL workbench

Tags: mysql

I am beginning to learn sql and the course I'm taking has you using Adventureworks as the sample db. The issue I'm having is I'm using a Mac. I have mssql running and downlaoded the .mdf adventureworks but it's "greyed out" when I try to connect it with workbench. Can someone explain to me the process of accomplishing this on a Mac? Thank you in advance.

Comment: MySQL Workbench is for working with MySQL databases. MS SQL Server is not MySQL. They're two different products. The first belongs to Oracle, the second belongs to Microsoft.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio is the SQL Server equivalent of Workbench. There are a couple of free editions of SQL Server available on the Microsoft website.

Comment: I am aware that MySQL is not the same thing as MS SQL server. Are you saying that workbench will not work with it?

Comment: @billy_caul MySQL Workbench is designed to work with MySQL only. There are other tools available that permit development against multiple RDBMS - it's really about what you want to do. But if you want to do something that requires you store your data in SQL Server, then I'd honestly suggest just installing SQL Server Management Studio, unless you have a good reason not to.